# why my jQuery ajax POST does not work by GET works fine?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have written a jquery ajax with `POST` but it didn't work. After hours of searching I found out that by changing to `GET` maybe the problem would solve. Fortunately it worked, but there still remains the question why `POST` does not work. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello this is my title</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#driver").click(function(event){
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: { name:"Zara" },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#stage').html(data);},
                    error: function(j,t,e) {
                        $('#stage').text('An error occurred= ' + j + " *** " + t + " *** " + e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Click on the button to load login.php file −</p>

<div id = "stage" style = "background-color:wheat;">
    STAGE
</div>

<input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Load Data" />

</body>
</html>
```

---

and this is the PHP Code:

---

```
if( empty($_REQUEST['name'] )) {
    $_REQUEST['name'] = "Error";
}

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
echo "Welcome ". $name;
```

After running this code it says "not found". I've searched the entire web, jquery official website and all similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me!

=========

## edit

this is the request header:

---

```
Host: localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:63342/untitled2/index.php?_ijt=qgukfccd8om4ruh3e8fv7v8rds
Content-Length: 9
Cookie: Phpstorm-ed364c84=959e64e3-228a-4a78-904d-cc31d3f1a3e0
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

and this is request body:

```
name=Zara
```

---

this is the response:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1>
<hr/><p style="text-align: center">
PhpStorm 2016.2.1</p>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: If it says "not found" then you have not provided us with the code which would produce that response.

Comment: i did not watch the request response in browser developers. yes i included correctly as i said GET method works fine. yes it says "Not Found". no i run it on my local labtop.

Comment: An AJAX request requires a webserver. It will not just run on your local laptop which explains why the post did not work.

Comment: it is possible that the login.php is validating $_GET rather then $_POST so if you have a if statement like if(isset($_GET['name'])){ code to execute } and no else  block which would contain a echo statement. you would end up getting nothing returned even though the post did work but no response

Comment: Are you sure !? if this is the case then the problem disappears instantly, are you sure, because i have XAMP !? doesn't that simulate web-server!?

Comment: so you change `type:"POST"` to `type:"GET"` and the 404 goes away, without any other changes? That wouldn't be a JS/ajax problem, that'd be something on your server doing a bad rewrite

Comment: Who says "Not Found", and how did you know that you were getting a Not Found response if you were not watching the ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AJAX request requires a webserver. It will not just run on your local laptop which explains why the POST did not do anything.

In order to fix this you can install a webserver with PHP on your laptop. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) are two packages which come to mind.

Comment: i have XAMP installed.

Comment: you can still POST to a local file. it just won't actually DO anything. and certainly wouldn't produce a 404.

Comment: Having XAMPP installed and placing the files there properly are 2 different things too. You need to open the developer tools on your browser and watch the request / response of your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this,

```
    if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $_POST['name'] = "Error";
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "Welcome ". $name;
```

Comment: It's clearly saying that file not found. Once try running the code independently. I mean, run login.php directly from the browser. we'll see what does it show.

Answer (score 0):

after hours and hours of struggling i finally found out that my problem.
as you may have encountered this kind of problems, my problem had a real simple solution, because i worked on PhpStorm i had php installed from bitNami XAMP on phpstorm so my php scrips worked fine until Post request, in which it requires a webserver as **Jay** mentioned it , the solution was:

**i copied my files on XAMP, htdocs folder and it ran perfectly fine.**